# Cocos2d: Stick two CCSprite?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, chipmunk

I am trying to superimpose sprites by drag and drop and when to sprites collide I want to stick them so if one fall the other sprite stack on it will fall two. Any ideas please?

Best regards

For more precision I need help on the stick part. Thanks

Comment: Which part are you having issues with? Dragging sprites? Colliding detection? Just the 'stick' part?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. The stick part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd follow these steps.-

- Extend `CCSprite` to add a property `CCSprite *spriteToFollow`
- You should also add a `CGPoint` to store the offset between two sprites when they collide.
- Once one `CustomSprite` collides with another one, set the proper `spriteToFollow`
- On `CustomSprite init` method, call to `scheduleUpdate`
- On `update` method, if `spriteToFollow` exists, update the current to `spriteToFollow.position + offset`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi ssantos, In fact that's what I did, but I think that there is a better way to do it like this, and I have no idea how to implement it, please see the demo in the link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgJJZTS0aMM

Comment: Oh, didn't notice the `chipmunk` part, my bad. I'm more into `box2d`, but you should be able to detect the collision between two bodies (the term in box2d is `contactListener`), and then attaching them with each other using the chipmunk equivalent to a `distanceJoint`. Best of lucks :)